# Adding Sound to HTML5 Canvas not working while exporting to video

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Brief Description:: We are creating `HTML5 canvas` with some text on it. But when we export that canvas to video by right click and `save video as`, then video is created successfully but it is without sound.

Here is our code:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var video = document.querySelector("video");

var colors = ["pink","brown"];
function draw (){
    ctx.fillStyle = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 
}
draw();
    var audio = new Audio("https://sapphireprofits.com/liveliness/1636612975562.mp3");
     audio.play();

var videoStream = canvas.captureStream(30);
var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(videoStream);

var chunks = [];
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
  chunks.push(e.data);
};

mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
  var blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'video/mp4' });
  chunks = [];
  var videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  video.src = videoURL;
};
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
  chunks.push(e.data);
};

mediaRecorder.start();
setInterval(draw, 300);
setTimeout(function (){ mediaRecorder.stop(); }, 5000);
```

```html
<canvas width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<video autoplay controls></video>
```

Here is the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0huwn3s/2/) link

You will listen the audio but in the below generated `videostream media recorder`, **when you play , audio is not audible**

Comment: As far as I know a canvas does not have sound ... do you have any documentation supporting that it does?

Comment: There is a `MediaStream.addTrack()` maybe that is what you are looking for:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/addTrack